# Converting integer to date in R and calculating no. of days in between?

Tags: r

I have the below date info in an R dataframe "Date" with 3 columns Serial, Date A & Date B

Date <
Serial :
1
2
3
4
5

Date A:     20111113 20111113 20111113 20111113 20111113

Date B :
20120420
20160517
20120915
20130505
20121221

Now Date A & Date B are integers

I need to -
a)Convert Date A and Date B into YY-MM-DD format
b)Calculate the "number of days" between the two dates and store it onto a new column in the df for each Serial.

I tried a)  using as.Date , as.POSIXct.date but to no avail.
Am still stuck with step a) itself. 
Help appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it using `as.Date`

```
as.Date("20111113", format = "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2011-11-13"

as.Date("20111113", format = "%Y%m%d") - as.Date("20120420", format = "%Y%m%d")
#Time difference of -159 days
```

You can also use `anydate` command of `anytime` package to parse integer into date and obtain the difference by subtracting.

```
library(anytime)

anydate(20111113)
#[1] "2011-11-13"

anydate(20111113) - anydate(20120420)
#Time difference of -159 days
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` here: first parse the dates with `ymd` (or `ydm`, in case your dates are in the form "YYYY-DD-MM"), then compute the difference with `difftime` or simply with `Date_A - Date_B`.

When parsing the dates you could choose between `mutate_all` and `mutate_at`, depending whether all columns should be parsed or just specific ones. Since you seem to have an index column, in this case you would use `mutate_at`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


my_dat %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Date_A", "Date_B"), funs(ymd)) %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = difftime(Date_B, Date_A))
#>       Date_A     Date_B date_diff
#> 1 2011-11-13 2012-04-20  159 days
#> 2 2011-11-13 2016-05-17 1647 days
#> 3 2011-11-13 2012-09-15  307 days
#> 4 2011-11-13 2013-05-05  539 days
#> 5 2011-11-13 2012-12-21  404 days
```

Data:

```r
zzz <- "Date_A  Date_B
20111113    20120420
20111113    20160517
20111113    20120915
20111113    20130505
20111113    20121221"

my_dat <- read.table(text = zzz, header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
a <- strptime(c("20111113", "20111113", "20111113", "20111113", "20111113"), "%Y%m%d")
b <- strptime(c("20120420", "20160517", "20120915", "20130505", "20121221"), "%Y%m%d")

> as.numeric(difftime(b, a, units="days"))
[1]  158.9583 1646.9583  306.9583  538.9583  404.0000
```